# Get feature importance from GridSearchCV

Tags: python, scikit-learn, grid-search

Is there a way to get feature importance from a sklearn's GridSearchCV?

For example :

```
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
print("starting grid search ......")
optimized_GBM = GridSearchCV(LGBMRegressor(),
                             params,
                             cv=3,
                             n_jobs=-1)
# 
optimized_GBM.fit(tr, yvar)
preds2 = optimized_GBM.predict(te)
```

Is there a way I can access feature importance ?

Maybe something like

```
optimized_GBM.feature_importances_
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Got it. It goes something like this :

```
optimized_GBM.best_estimator_.feature_importance()
```

if you happen ran this through a Pipeline and receive `object has no attribute 'feature_importance'` try
   optimized_GBM.best_estimator_.named_steps["step_name"].feature_importances_

where `step_name` is the corresponding name in your pipeline

Comment: Did you maybe got `object has no attribute 'feature_importance'` error?

Comment: No,I did not get any error. This worked for me. I was using python 3.6. However, this was in Jan so the function call might have changed as suggested by other answer.

Answer (score 35):

This one works

```
optimized_GBM.best_estimator_.feature_importances_
```

Comment: In addition: If you are using a pipeline, .i.e. your estimator is a pipeline object, you have to add the pipeline step name: `optimized_GBM.best_estimator_.named_steps["step_name"].feature_importances_`

Comment: @aptha-gowda  is there a way to also extract the feature names? i.e. the name of the variable?

Comment: @00schneider if I do PCA then fit a model in my pipeline, how do I recover the importance of the original variables in the model.

Answer (score 3):

That depends on what model you have selected. If you choose a SVM you wont be having feature importance parameter, but in decision trees you will get it